# How can i obtain service in ViewModel which binding a ContentView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Description
1、I create ContentView named LeftContent in views floder，and create viewmodel named LeftContentViewModel，then use “prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" bind them
2、create ITestInterface class and implement TestInterface，and register in App class
3、In LeftContentViewModel constructor，add parameter ITestInterface
4、when runninng,error occur. code and eception as follow
thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try removing comment **containerRegistery.RegisterForNavigation<PrismContentPage1>()** from **RegisterType** method in **App.cs** file

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'System.Object', name = 'PrismContentPage1'.

Looking at your RegisterTypes, you've only added a registration for your service and have commented out the registrations for your views. Also note that your ViewModel should have a single constructor.